# Adding custom select fields to a Django query

Tags: django

I have a database table of jobs, some of which have been paid, others not. The payments are represented as rows in another table with a foreign key referencing the jobs table. I want one field in the result set of jobs to indicate whether a payment exists ("`is_paid`").

So far, I have been doing `Job.objects.annotate(num_payments=Count('payment'))` and then using `num_payments > 0` as my boolean indicator of payment. However, this feels like a hack. Another way is to use `extra()`, but it seems you lose some flexibility and portability when using that.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You doing it right and I don't feel it like a hack.  This is the most efficient way to do it without using SQL in the `extra()`. The only thing to suggest is to name the field `is_paid` instead of `num_payments`:

```
Job.objects.annotate(is_paid=Count('payment'))
```

`0` count in boolean context is `False` so you can safely use it in the `if` statement like:

```
if job.is_paid:
    ...
```

Or, in the template:

```
{{ job.is_paid|yesno:"PAID" }}
```